# How to $group with $lookup pipeline in MongoDB Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I have a document with field `package` that is an array referencing other documents by their groupid:
(Few examples from the `products` collection)

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5fa***********"),
    groupid: "ffc629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
    description: "DC Ultima",
    size: "XL",
    itemcode: "5446010",
    barcode: 14000,
    package: [
        {
            description: "Force Sea Blue 2021"
            groupid: "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
        },
        {
            description: "Force Toxic Green 2021",
            groupid: "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7"
        },
        {
            description: "Force Asadachi 2021",
            groupid: "dfc12a02-7123-42d0-b5b1-77ffd299fabd"
        }
    ],

    ...
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("5fb***********"),
    groupid: "ffc629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
    description: "DC Ultima",
    size: "S",
    itemcode: "5446009",
    barcode: 14000,
    package: [
        {
            description: "Force Sea Blue 2021"
            groupid: "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
        },
        {
            description: "Force Toxic Green 2021",
            groupid: "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7"
        },
        {
            description: "Force Asadachi 2021",
            groupid: "dfc12a02-7123-42d0-b5b1-77ffd299fabd"
        }
    ],

    ...
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("5ee***********"),
    groupid: "daa629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
    description: "FOX Tribute",
    size: "XXL",
    itemcode: "449767",
    barcode: 16000,
    package: [
        {
            description: "Renthal Absolute"
            groupid: "z6b629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
        },
    ],

    ...
}
```

I am able to use `$lookup` to get documents referenced by groupid in package array:

```
db.collection('products').aggregate([
    { $match: { groupid: groupid } },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$groupid",
        description: { $last: "$description" },
        sizepricesdiscountqty: { 
            $push: { size: "$size", price: "$barcode", discount: "$discount", qty: 
                   "$qty", barcode: "$itemcode" } 
            },
        package: { $last: "$package" }
    } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: "products",
        localField: "package.groupid",
        foreignField: "groupid",
        as: "packageProds",
    } },
]).toArray().then((result)=>{
    console.log(result)
})
```

The output looks like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5fa***********"),
        groupid: "ffc629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
        description: "DC Ultima",
        sizepricesdiscountqty: [
            {
                size: "S", price: 14000, discount: 0, qty: 3 
                barcode: "5446009"
            }
        ]
        package: [
            {
                description: "Force Sea Blue 2021"
                groupid: "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
            },
            {
                description: "Force Toxic Green 2021",
                groupid: "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7"
            },
            {
                description: "Force Asadachi 2021",
                groupid: "dfc12a02-7123-42d0-b5b1-77ffd299fabd"
            }
        ],
        packageProds: [
            {
                description: "Force Sea Blue 2021"
                groupid: "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
                size: "xs"
            },
            {
                description: "Force Sea Blue 2021"
                groupid: "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
                size: "s"
            },
            {
                description: "Force Sea Blue 2021"
                groupid: "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
                size: "l"
            },
            {
                description: "Force Toxic Green 2021",
                groupid: "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7",
                size: "m"
            },
            {
                description: "Force Toxic Green 2021",
                groupid: "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7",
                size: "xs"
            },
            {
                description: "Force Asadachi 2021",
                groupid: "dfc12a02-7123-42d0-b5b1-77ffd299fabd",
                size: "xs"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The problem is that `packageProds` contains every single document with the matching group id. What I need is to return one document per groupid with `sizepricesdiscountqty` field containing data from other documents with the same matching groupid. (Pretty much using the same code above lookup operator a using it within lookup.)

I tried to use the pipeline operator in lookup like this:

```
{ $lookup: {
    from: "products",
    let: { group_id: "$package.groupid" },
    pipeline: [
        { $match: { groupid: "$$group_id" }  },
        { $group: {
            _id: "$$group_id",
            description: { $last: "$description" },
            sizepricesdiscountqty: { 
            $push: { size: "$size", price: "$barcode", discount: "$discount", qty: "$qty", 
                   barcode: "$itemcode" } 
            },
    ],
    as: "packageProds",
} },
```

But this would return packageProds as an empty array. How Can I get group the documents by the referenced groupid within the lookup? I think I should be able to do it in pipeline but it seems it doesn't get the value of `$package.groupid` while it does get it when using `localField: "package.groupid` but then I can't use pipeline operator.

The output I am looking for would be something like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5fa***********"),
        groupid: "ffc629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
        description: "DC Ultima",
        sizepricesdiscountqty: [
            {
                size: "S", price: 14000, discount: 0, qty: 3 
                barcode: "5446009"
            }
        ]
        package: [
            {
                description: "Force Sea Blue 2021"
                groupid: "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
            },
            {
                description: "Force Toxic Green 2021",
                groupid: "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7"
            },
            {
                description: "Force Asadachi 2021",
                groupid: "dfc12a02-7123-42d0-b5b1-77ffd299fabd"
            }
        ],
        packageProds: [
            {
                description: "Force Sea Blue 2021"
                groupid: "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
                size: "xs"
                sizepricesdiscountqty: [
                    {
                        size: "s",
                        ...
                    },
                    {
                        size: "l",
                        ...
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                description: "Force Toxic Green 2021",
                groupid: "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7",
                size: "m",
                sizepricesdiscountqty: [
                    {
                        size: "xs",
                        ...
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                description: "Force Asadachi 2021",
                groupid: "dfc12a02-7123-42d0-b5b1-77ffd299fabd",
                size: "xs",
                sizepricesdiscountqty: []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Post some documents of `products` collection and the expected output format. Are you performing self join on `products` collection?

Comment: I edited the first block of code. There are few examples of documents in products collection. Basically there could be same products, but difference would be the sizes and so groupid field would reference the same product with slight differences in quantity, sizes and barcodes.
I'm not sure what you mean by self join. I just get one product by groupid but create sizepricesdiscountqty field that holds details from other products having same groupid.

Comment: None. `sizepricesdiscountqty` it's an output array that stores data from other document's that have the same groupid that is used in `{ $match: { groupid: groupid } }`

Comment: Can u attach some expected output. Its not clear from your explanation.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat Did some edits. Hope it's more clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let groupid = "ffc629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0";

db.products.aggregate([
    { $match: { groupid: groupid } },
    {
        $addFields: { "packageProds": "$package" }
    },
    { $unwind: "$packageProds" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$packageProds.groupid",
            pkgDescription: { $last: "$packageProds.description" },
            groupid: { $last: "$groupid" },
            description: { $last: "$description" },
            size: { $last: "$size" },
            price: { $last: "$price" },
            barcode: { $last: "$barcode" },
            package: { $last: "$package" },
            sizepricesdiscountqty: {
                $push: {
                    size: "$size",
                    price: "$price",
                    barcode: "$barcode"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$groupid",
            groupid: { $last: "$groupid" },
            description: { $last: "$description" },
            sizepricesdiscountqty: {
                $last: {
                    size: "$size",
                    price: "$price",
                    barcode: "$barcode"
                }
            },
            package: { $last: "$package" },
            packageProds: {
                $push: {
                    description: "$pkgDescription",
                    groupid: "$_id",
                    size: "$size",
                    sizepricesdiscountqty: "$sizepricesdiscountqty"
                }
            }
        }
    },
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : "ffc629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0",
    "groupid" : "ffc629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0",
    "description" : "DC Ultima",
    "sizepricesdiscountqty" : {
        "size" : "S",
        "price" : 14000,
        "barcode" : "5446009"
    },
    "package" : [
        {
            "description" : "Force Sea Blue 2021",
            "groupid" : "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
        },
        {
            "description" : "Force Toxic Green 2021",
            "groupid" : "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7"
        },
        {
            "description" : "Force Asadachi 2021",
            "groupid" : "dfc12a02-7123-42d0-b5b1-77ffd299fabd"
        }
    ],
    "packageProds" : [
        {
            "description" : "Force Toxic Green 2021",
            "groupid" : "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7",
            "size" : "S",
            "sizepricesdiscountqty" : [
                {
                    "size" : "XL",
                    "price" : 14000,
                    "barcode" : "5446010"
                },
                {
                    "size" : "S",
                    "price" : 14000,
                    "barcode" : "5446009"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "description" : "Force Sea Blue 2021",
            "groupid" : "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0",
            "size" : "S",
            "sizepricesdiscountqty" : [
                {
                    "size" : "XL",
                    "price" : 14000,
                    "barcode" : "5446010"
                },
                {
                    "size" : "S",
                    "price" : 14000,
                    "barcode" : "5446009"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "description" : "Force Asadachi 2021",
            "groupid" : "dfc12a02-7123-42d0-b5b1-77ffd299fabd",
            "size" : "S",
            "sizepricesdiscountqty" : [
                {
                    "size" : "XL",
                    "price" : 14000,
                    "barcode" : "5446010"
                },
                {
                    "size" : "S",
                    "price" : 14000,
                    "barcode" : "5446009"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Test data:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/9/2021, 7:43:10 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60478276c53e863f4037eb44"),
    "groupid" : "ffc629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0",
    "description" : "DC Ultima",
    "size" : "XL",
    "barcode" : "5446010",
    "price" : 14000,
    "package" : [
        {
            "description" : "Force Sea Blue 2021",
            "groupid" : "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
        },
        {
            "description" : "Force Toxic Green 2021",
            "groupid" : "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7"
        },
        {
            "description" : "Force Asadachi 2021",
            "groupid" : "dfc12a02-7123-42d0-b5b1-77ffd299fabd"
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/9/2021, 7:43:10 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60478276c53e863f4037eb45"),
    "groupid" : "ffc629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0",
    "description" : "DC Ultima",
    "size" : "S",
    "barcode" : "5446009",
    "price" : 14000,
    "package" : [
        {
            "description" : "Force Sea Blue 2021",
            "groupid" : "d6c629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
        },
        {
            "description" : "Force Toxic Green 2021",
            "groupid" : "36508de4-4ca0-4cf8-9ed8-796efc8a49e7"
        },
        {
            "description" : "Force Asadachi 2021",
            "groupid" : "dfc12a02-7123-42d0-b5b1-77ffd299fabd"
        }
    ]
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/9/2021, 7:43:10 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60478276c53e863f4037eb46"),
    "groupid" : "daa629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0",
    "description" : "FOX Tribute",
    "size" : "XXL",
    "barcode" : "449767",
    "price" : 16000,
    "package" : [
        {
            "description" : "Renthal Absolute",
            "groupid" : "z6b629a4-98f1-46bc-8d96-04a8fc899eb0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The output is the one I am getting already. The output I am looking for is the last block of code I wrote in the edit.

Comment: In other words, the products in packageProds should be grouped by the same groupid and than each group would have sizepricesdiscountqty field that would contain the values that differ such as size or barcode. 
(I am sorry for my english, it is not my first language so explaining this problem in simple words is difficult for me.) Thanks a lot for taking your time for this.

Comment: The data you have attached and the expected output is highly inconsistent. Match them to get the exact answer. For example the value of `barcode` in data is present in `price` field of "output", `discount` and `qty` are missing in data but present in "output".

Comment: No worries for a late response. Busy here as well, thanks a bunch for the help. It's very close what I'm looking for, but still not quite. I will work on it for a while and see if I can get to the result I need.